# Replace or Delete specific symbols from text file without RegEx in Python

Tags: python, csv, replace

I want to replace or delete specific symbols like "" or '' from my text file. I have a little script that open a specific path with Example.txt file. Also, I replace \n to white space. When I put .replace('""','') not works.

**My output is:**

> "Ejemplo, hagsvdjbnls jhsbdjw wkednslwe,dcjbek uisidn ckwdnlnkw
>   bwuedhlwe qkjwb" kjwbdkw. " kjwebdsklwe d" kqjwndlkw w" kjwebdlkw
>   d"kwjbdwekne , ahjvduins¢ &&&&& "" qkjbdnlkqw"""

**My code is:**

```
# coding=utf-8
import csv

def scan_folder():
    file_path = '/Users/.../Example.txt'
    with open('Example.csv', 'w') as csvFile:
        mensaje = open(file_path).read()
        mensaje = mensaje.replace("\n", "").replace('""', '')

        csvData = [mensaje]
        csvData = [str(data).replace('\n', '').replace('\r', '') for data in csvData]
        writer = csv.writer(csvFile, delimiter=';')
        writer.writerow(csvData)
scan_folder()
```

As you can see finally I write in a csv the output. Also **I want that my output to be** the same without " " or/and &&.

> Ejemplo, hagsvdjbnls jhsbdjw wkednslwe,dcjbek uisidn ckwdnlnkw
>   bwuedhlwe qkjwb kjwbdkw.  kjwebdsklwe d kqjwndlkw w kjwebdlkw
>   dkwjbdwekne , ahjvduins¢   qkjbdnlkqw

Comment: You are writing to a `.csv` file and your data contains a comma. That data will be surrounded by `"` characters because that is how the `.csv` format indicates that the comma is part of the data and not a field delimiter.

Answer (score 3):

Use `str.replace('"', "")`

**Ex:**

```
s = '''"Ejemplo, hagsvdjbnls jhsbdjw wkednslwe,dcjbek uisidn ckwdnlnkw bwuedhlwe qkjwb" kjwbdkw. " kjwebdsklwe d" kqjwndlkw w" kjwebdlkw d"kwjbdwekne , ahjvduins¢ &&&&& "" qkjbdnlkqw"""'''
print(s.replace('"', "").replace('&', ""))
```

**Output:**

```
Ejemplo, hagsvdjbnls jhsbdjw wkednslwe,dcjbek uisidn ckwdnlnkw bwuedhlwe qkjwb kjwbdkw.  kjwebdsklwe d kqjwndlkw w kjwebdlkw dkwjbdwekne , ahjvduins¢   qkjbdnlkqw
```

Comment: @NitinPawar Only put the same but particularly for that symbol. replace('&', '') like in my answer below.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the answer is only to do a correct .replace('"', '') and also the same for '&' this specific symbol.

> csvData = [str(data).replace('\n', '').replace('\r', '').replace('"',
>   '').replace('&', '') for data in csvData]